# Is it possible/valid to qualify a node's value with a namespace?

Tags: xml, soap, soapfault

I've just come across this soap fault example, and I'm curious about the presence of the namespace in the value part, in an apparent attempt to reinforce the idea that the value present there corresponds to a certain namespace/domain.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap:Envelope 
    xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope'>
   <soap:Body>
      <soap:Fault>
         <faultcode>soap:VersionMismatch</faultcode>
         <faultstring, xml:lang='en">
            Message was not SOAP 1.1 compliant
         </faultstring>
         <faultactor>
            http://sample.org.ocm/jws/authnticator
         </faultactor>
      </soap:Fault>
   </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Note the `<faultcode>soap:VersionMismatch</faultcode>` part.

Does that construct actually apply to node values? And if it does, are there any rules that govern its use?

Thank you.

Comment: That is just content. It is completely arbitrary. Some parser could theoretically give it semantics but that would be orthogonal to the concept xml namespaces

Comment: That was my thought too. But what was the point of putting it there like that then? Especially if that specific node's value part is supposed to be limited to 4 different values. Why would anyone want to complicate things this much? Cause if we go through this path, we could get to really complex stuff that the validator would have to deal with. Like having to validate things like `<faultcode>asd:dasd:asdasd:VersionMismatch</faultcode>`. Would that still be valid and feasible to pass a soap test? This construct leads to so many questions that I wonder why at all did they even mentioned it.

Comment: Great point. I wish I knew.